# Compiling Octave 4.2.1 in linux, can't link to PCRE library with GCC 4.9.3

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker

When running the configure script for Octave, I do:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/include -L/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/lib/" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/lib"
```

I have also tried:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/include" LDFLAGS="-L/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/lib/" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/lib"
```

Both of these produce the same failure:

```
checking pcre.h usability... yes
checking pcre.h presence... no
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: pcre.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for pcre.h... yes
checking pcre/pcre.h usability... no
checking pcre/pcre.h presence... no
checking for pcre/pcre.h... no
checking whether pcre.h defines the macros we need... no
configure: error: to build Octave, you must have the PCRE library and header files installed
```

I'm lost as to how it can find pcre.h but fails to do anything else with it.  Am I doing something wrong on my configure line or is pcre broken?  If it's my configure line, how do I link against pcre correctly?
For reference, here's the pcre path:

```
ls /customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/
bin
include
lib
share
```

Comment: The expected order is apparently -I -L then -l     In the case of Octave, it's written to expect pcre to be in a system path, so loading an external version requires a lot of extra steps.  C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH had to be used to force gcc to point to my library.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with that for a while as well, but the solution was actually very simple. just use CPPFLAGS rather than CFLAGS for include files:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/include" LDFLAGS="-L/customlibs/pcre/gnu/8.40/lib/"
```

There's also no need for LD_LIBRARY_PATH upon configuring.